# Error in accessing global variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following js. The issue is that, I am unable to access the variable jasonServiceUrlObject in the getMajorGroups function. I've declared the variable globally but firebug throws a not defined error when the alert runs!

```
var jsonServiceUrlObject = null;

function loadServiceXml(){
    $.get("/xml/ServiceUrls.xml", function(xml){
        jsonServiceUrlObject = $.xml2json(xml);

    });
}

function getMajorGroups(){
  var element = $(".item-group-button").first();

  var serviceUrl = getServiceURL("getAllMajorGroups")
  alert(jsonServiceUrlObject.service[1].service_key);
  $.get(serviceUrl , function(data){
    if(data.majorGroups.length != 0){
      $('.panel_list').empty();
      element.empty();
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < data.majorGroups.length; i++){
      var clone = element.clone();
      clone.append("<h3>" + data.majorGroups[i].description + "</h3>");
      clone.attr("id", data.majorGroups[i].majorGroupId);
      $('.panel_list').append(clone);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: AJAX: **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML.

Comment: `};` at end of `loadServiceXml` function...may be typo

Comment: make sure `loadServiceXml` function called before `getMajorGroups` function so `loadServiceXml` function can set global variable.

Comment: @DipeshParmar looks fine to me.  semicolon is unneccessary but not wrong.

Comment: @DipeshParmar that won't be enough because the variable is set in a callback.  It actually needs to be run and have the callback execute before referencing it

Comment: how is these two method invoked, in what order

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX callback takes some time to return, after all the other functions are run. Hence the variable is not set when the function uses it. Try setting `async` to `false`. Then your code will wait until the AJAX call returns. OR you can call the function that uses the variable from inside the AJAX callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the variable before referencing it, just declaring it is not enough.  You haven't shown all your code, but I'm guessing thats not happening.

Note that running your first function before the second won't be sufficient, as the variable is defined within a callback.  If you want to run these functions consecutively you should call the second from within the callback of the first.

```
function loadServiceXml(){
    $.get("/xml/ServiceUrls.xml", function(xml){
        jsonServiceUrlObject = $.xml2json(xml);
        getMajorGroups();
    });
}
```